# Bash script which will take 10 command line arguments and print it

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am very new to programming and this is my first bash script.

I want to write a script which will take 10 commandline arguments and print it

Comment: it seems unclear for me.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html

Comment: @AvinashRaj a bash script that will take 10 arguments and will print it...basically prints 10 numbers by taking 10 command line parameters

Comment: What exactly are you having a problem with?  Please include the code you have already written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9 ${10}
```

Comment: why is 10 inside brackets?

Comment: Please test it without the brackets and with ten arguments.

Comment: If you run this script without the brackets and with ten arguments (e.g. `a b c d e f g h i j`) you should get the following: `a b c d e f g h i a0`.

Comment: `$10` is the expansion of the first argument followed by a literal 0.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, or am I missing something?

```
-mbp:~$ more test.sh 
first=$1
second=$2
echo $first is better than $second
-mbp:~$ sh test.sh r matlab
r is better than matlab
```